# this() and this('my_element') - only sthe second way works

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to work with the following code:

```
$('#xedit_DS').editable({
        prepend: 'not selected',
        inputclass: 'form-control',
        source: [".$source."],
        params: {
             job: 'xedit',
             pk_field: $(this).data('id-pk-field'),
             step: $(this).data('id-job-id')
        },
        display: function(value, sourceData) {
            var colors = {
                    '': 'gray',
                    1: 'green',
                    2: 'blue'
                },
                elem = $.grep(sourceData, function(o) {
                    return o.value == value;
                });

            //if (elem.length) {
            //    $(this).text(elem[0].text).css('color', colors[value]);
            //} else {
            //    $(this).empty();
            //}
        }
    });
```

It seems, that the part `pk_field: $(this).data('id-pk-field'),` won't work and I don't know why.

In the postfile there is no variable `pk_field`.

If I try it with `pk_field: $('#xedit_DS').data('id-pk-field'),`
it works. Why won't it work in the first way?

Comment: because the `this` that you think you have isn't the `this` you want. You can probably confirm this by simply putting `console.log(this)` at different points to check the context of the current instance of `this`.

Comment: how i can do it what i trie to do?

Comment: would need more info, editable is coming from what lib,  and is it the commented out line at the end that you are trying to do? `//if (elem.length) {....`